# Reading XML and writing to XML in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have an XML file

```xml
<DECLARE> 
    <xmlnsxsi>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"</xmlnsxsi>
    <xmlns>"http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository/admin</xmlns>
    <Database> 
        <mdsid>"m80000001-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000"</mdsid>
        <name>"PBCS"</name>
        <xmlnsxsi>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"</xmlnsxsi>
        <xmlns>"http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository"</xmlns>
        <type>"Oracle11g"</type>
        <dbName>"Oracle 11g"</dbName>
        <dbTypeId>"57"</dbTypeId>
        <Feature name="LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
        <Feature name="RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
        <Feature name="FULL_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
        <Feature name="NESTED_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
        <Feature name="UNION_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
        <Feature name="UNION_ALL_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
    </Database>
    <PhysicalTable mdsid="mc000002a-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">
        <name>FCT_PBCS</name>
        <xmlnsxsi>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xmlnsxsi>
        <xmlns>http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository</xmlns>
        <type>none</type> 
        <maxConn>0</maxConn>
        <containerRef>"/oracle/bi/server/base/Schema/80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000.xml#m80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000"</containerRef>
    </PhysicalTable>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002b-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">
        <name>ACCT_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE </dataType>
        <precision>22</precision> 
        <nullable>true</nullable> 
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002c-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>CURR_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002d-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>DATE_KEY</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002e-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>ENTITY_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002f-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>MONTHLY_VAL</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000030-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>MONTH_NAME</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000031-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c4800000">   
        <name>PLAN_ELE_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000032-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>PROD_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000033-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>REVE_DRIV_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000034-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>SCENA_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000035-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>TRANS_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000036-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>VER_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc0000037-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>YEAR_YY</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
</DECLARE>
```

I'm parsing it with ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xtree = et.parse('input.xml')
xroot = xtree.getroot()

for node in xroot.iter():
    print(node.tag,node.attrib,node.text)
```

I'm getting the whole XML file, now I want to write this back as an XML file. So the objective is build Python code that will give back the result same as the input XML file.

Is my coding correct? Also can someone say how to write the output back to a XML file.

Comment: *"How to write an ElementTree to a file"* is in the documentation. Please try that first.

Comment: @Aarush How's this? xtree.write('out.xml')